# Appropriate pattern for injector that sets a property and client that ONLY gets a property

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, object-oriented-design

Suppose I have a method in client code that expects an interface...

```
void DoWork(IDataManager data) {
    //use IDataManager interface in the DoWork method
}
```

And the *IDataManager* interface looks like this...

```
public interface IDataManager {
    ITypeAData TypeAData { get; }
    ITypeBData TypeBData { get; }
}
```

And each IType*Data interface just allows some data to be accessed...

```
public interface ITypeAData {
    int Value { get; }
}

//similar def for ITypeBData...
```

Currently the code that is providing the `IDataManager` to the `DoWork` client method defines the interfaces kinda like this...

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager {
    ITypeAData TypeAData { get; private set; }
    ITypeBData TypeBData { get; private set; }

    public DataManager(ITypeAData typeAData, ITypeBData typeBData) {
        TypeAData = typeAData;
        TypeBData = typeBData;
    } 
}

public class TypeAData : ITypeAData {
    private int privateValue;
    public int Value {
        get {
            return privateValue;
        }
        set {
            privateValue = value;
        }
    }
}

//something similar for TypeBData : ITypeBData
```

And then I do something like this...

```
DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(new TypeAData(), new TypeBData());
//other setup activities
(dataManager.TypeAData as TypeAData).Value = 0; //value is not relevant
```

Keep in mind that the code defining the `DoWork` method is in one assembly, the code that defines the interfaces is in a second, and the code that defines the implementations of the interfaces is in a third.

I think this smells a little because in order to set the value of my dataManager's `TypeAData.Value` property I need to cast to a concrete implementation of `ITypeAData`. Is this okay because the code providing the instance of `ITypeAData` is *supposed to know* the implementation that it is providing? Or is there some pattern I should be using?

The reason I'm using a setter on the Value properties of `TypeAData` and `TypeBData` is because the `DoWork` method can be called multiple times **while** the data that `TypeAData` encapsulates changes. The whole point is to pass contextual information from the place where the `DataManager` is created into the `DoWork` method. This contextual information can change over multiple calls to `DoWork`. Hence a property. I suppose I could always create a new `TypeAData` and `TypeBData` every time I create a `DataManager` and set the Value via the constructor. But for some reason it feels more appropriate to have one `TypeAData` and one `TypeBData` and "configure" them before each call to `DoWork`

Comment: Any good reason that you're completely avoiding constructors?

Comment: *in order to set the value of my dataManager's TypeAData.Value property I need to cast to a concrete implementation of ITypeAData* That isn't completely accurate. If you cast to an implementation of ITypeAData, you still wouldn't be able to set the Value property, because the interface does not expose a setter. That is the problem. It's not an issue of interface vs concrete. You just aren't exposing the property that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is contradictory.

Here, you state that the content of your `ITypeAData` object is intended as a read-only value:

```
public interface ITypeAData {
    int Value { get; }
}
```

Here, you clearly intend to be able to set the value of your `ITypeAData` content:

```
(dataManager.TypeAData as TypeAData).Value = 0;
```

This is contradictory.

Either it's intended to be immutable (by the consumer who only knows the object by its interface), or it's not.

- If it is a read-only object, then you shouldn't be trying to set its values here.
- If it isn't a read-only object, then your interface needs to be expanded to also have a setter.
- As a third possibility, if the interface should be read-only but the manager should be able to change the values, then the manager needs to know this object by its concrete type, i.e.:

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager {
    TypeAData TypeAData { get; private set; }
    // and so on...
}
```

This can also be done without the manager's consumer having access to the setters, while the manager itself does have access:

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager {

    private TypeAData _typeAData; // set your values by referencing this

    public ITypeAData TypeAData => _typeAData; // expose this to your consumers
}
```

This way, the manager can access the setters but the consumer of the manager cannot.

Which of these options is correct is a contextual decision, and your vague example code makes it impossible for us to judge which is the appropriate approach here.

---

> I think this smells a little because in order to set the value of my dataManager's TypeAData.Value property I need to cast to a concrete implementation of ITypeAData. Is this okay because the code providing the instance of ITypeAData is supposed to know the implementation that it is providing? Or is there some pattern I should be using?

Based on the generic example code you've provided, I can't think of a case where knowing a type without declaring it as that known type is a good approach. In most if not all cases, this is polymorphism abuse.

That being said, there may be a contextual consideration why it's an acceptable approach here. For example, some deserialization returns `object` types and expects its consumer to cast it to the desired type. I don't think this is a great approach for a library, but if that's the library you're working with, you haven't really got a choice.

I can't exclude the possibility that you may need to do it the way you're doing it now, simply because I don't know of any contextual considerations. Though I do doubt that it's better to avoid this approach altogether - if it can be avoided in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as an aside, you are putting a lot of pointless code in your data classes. The `private set` is not needed unless you are using an ancient version of the language (removing it works with v6+ of C#, I think):

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager {
    ITypeAData TypeAData { get; }
    ITypeBData TypeBData { get; }

    DataManager(ITypeAData typeAData, ITypeBData typeBData) {
        TypeAData = typeAData;
        TypeBData = typeBData;
    } 
}
```

And `TypeAData` can be hugely simplified:

```
public class TypeAData : ITypeAData 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Beyond that, yes casting to the concrete type in the way you are is a definite anti-pattern. And it seems completely unnecessary. Just re-order the code:

```
//other setup activities
var typeAData = new TypeAData { Value = 0 }; //value is not relevant
var dataManager = new DataManager(typeAData, new TypeBData());
```

and the need for the cast goes away. And that `set` could go away too by adding a constructor to `TypeAData`:

```
public class TypeAData : ITypeAData 
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public TypeAData(int value) => Value = value;
}

//other setup activities
var typeAData = new TypeAData(0); //value is not relevant
var dataManager = new DataManager(typeAData, new TypeBData());
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Please see my edit in the original post that describes my motivation for a property

Comment: I would edit my comment above but I meant to say setter* not property*